# Limitations on the image in the Offers schema?

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

Are there restrictions on image file types that can be used as part of the new Offers schema? PNG, JPG, GIF, animated GIF?

Also, will these images be cached the same way images are now being cached inside email messages themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Offer schema doesn't introduce any additional restrictions on the image file types that are supported inside emails. Animated GIFs will be rendered as static.

The caching logic is the same that is used for images inside the email body.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

- Adding `Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0` will cause Gmail to refetch the image each time the message list is rendered in Grid View.
- Images can be as small as 233x161 although this is "unofficial".
- The Grid View display space is 290x200 which is half of the recommended 580x400 which leads me to believe the recommended dimension is for "retina" purposes.